# GADRequest request delegate does not always receive resposne

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, admob, google-dfp

I am working on an iOS app that uses Google Ad SDK. The view controller that is supposed to display the ad is a delegate of GADBannerViewDelegate and GADSwipeableBannerViewDelegate.

The ad comes in just fine most of the time. Sometimes however, AdMob seems to hang and I don't get a response whatsoever in my delegate.

Is there something I have done wrong? Alternatively, is there a way to detect this behavior?

I initialize the ad banner and then in viewWillAppear I reload the ad (assuming it's not already loading). It usually works just fine but again, it sometimes doesn't.

Here is the relevant code:

UPDATE::
I changed the code but to no avail. Here is new code (got rid of previous two methods):

```
-(void)resetAdView:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
    [self.adMob_ActivityIndicator startAnimating];
    if (adBanner_ == nil) {
        adBanner_ = [[DFPSwipeableBannerView alloc]
                     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 365, 300, 150)];
    }    
    [adBanner_ setHidden:YES];
    if (isLoaded_) {
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [adBanner_ loadRequest:request];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:adBanner_];
    } else {
        adBanner_.delegate = self;
        adBanner_.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        adBanner_.adUnitID = AD_UNIT_ID;
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [adBanner_ loadRequest:request];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:adBanner_];
    }
}
```

My instance variables are :

> DFPSwipeableBannerView *adBanner_; 
>   BOOL isLoaded_;

Comment: I used this a good amount for my code: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just wiping the banner view from the superview and completely re-initializing it and the request. This doesn't solve the problem of the hanging response but now if you switch to a different view and come back to this one, the ad does reload. It's possible that I was simply adding too many views into my scrollview which will not be the case anymore.

```
-(void)resetAdView:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
    // in reset method
    [self.adMob_ActivityIndicator startAnimating];
    adBanner_ = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in self.scrollView.subviews) {
        if (subview.tag == 666) {
            // removing banner view from superview
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    // (re) initializing banner view
    adBanner_ = [[DFPSwipeableBannerView alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 365, 300, 150)];
    [adBanner_ setHidden:YES];
    // setting up and requesting ad
    adBanner_.delegate = self;
    adBanner_.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    adBanner_.adUnitID = AD_UNIT_ID;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [adBanner_ loadRequest:request];
    adBanner_.tag = 666;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:adBanner_];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to lack of ad inventory.

Did you implement the banner view's error catching delegate function?

- (void)adView:(DFPBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error

If this delegate method isn't implemented in your code, implement it and log the error object to get a detailed error description.

Comment: I did implement the error catching delegate, yes. That delegate works as expected. When there is no ad or no network connection it fails with an error. The issue here is that it is not failing with an error or loading an ad. There is really just no response.